# AngularJS Order By Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, filter

I have an array that I am using ng-repeat on within the view html:

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="result in $ctrl.accaBuilderResults | orderBy: $ctrl.getSort">
           {{result.TipText}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have a function within my controller called 'getSort' which sorts the array by a property:

```
ctrl.getSort = function (result) {
    return result.TipConfidence;
};
```

This will sort the array by the TipConfidence property, by default in Ascending. How do I make it sort by Descending as I will be adding if/switch expression depending on the state of the user I will have to order by descending.

There is a $filter.orderBy functionality I could also use on the controller on the array before sending it to the view, but I will be having arrays within arrays so it won't be able to work that way, e.g.:

```
array = [
 [0] = { match: [], tip: [] },
 [1] = { match: [], tip: [] }
];
```

Comment: Using the AngularJS filter, you can alter the order by putting a `+` or `-` in front of the property you're ordering by. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#ordering-a-table-with-ngrepeat- . Alternatively, you can `reverse()` an array, or just sort descending w/this: `myarray.sort(function(a, b){return b-a})`

Comment: return "-" + result.TipConfidence doesen't seem to work?

Comment: Does this not work? `<li ng-repeat="result in $ctrl.accaBuilderResults | orderBy: -TipConfidence">`

Comment: I've solved the problem thanks. Just do: return -result.TipConfidence rather than return "-" + result.TipConfidence